# How to get latest entries, after X number?

Tags: templating, entries

I have a site where I want to feature the latest 5 entries and show the next 10 in a separate list. How would I do this?

The first part would be easy: `craft.entries.section('news').limit(5)`

But I can't figure out how to bring the next 10. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [offset](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#offset).

So if you want entries 6-15 it would be:

```
craft.entries.section('news').offset(5).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 6):

In the way you have described that you want to use all the results on the page but just moved and used in chunks you should save a query on the database and use [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) over `offset`.

```
{% set entriesList = craft.entries.section('news').limit(15) %}

{# Featured #}
{% for entries in entriesList | slice(0, 5) %}
{% endfor %}

{# Other List#}
{% for entries in entriesList | slice(4, 10) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Answer from jnowladn using slices above works but note that it has a type you need to correct first - he calls 'entriesList' and then refers to it as 'entriesLists' in the slices which won't work - they need to be called the same thing. Slices are ace, saved me a bit of head scratching on listings pages.